# what is the regex for first character is a letter?

Tags: regex

What is the regex so that the first character is always a letter and the rest can be either letters or numbers or nothing at all?

I have this which works when you input at least two characters, but it doesnt work when you input just one letter and nothing else.

```
/^[A-z][A-z0-9]+$/
```

what do I have to modify so it allows just one letter?
thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your regex is not right:

```
/^[A-z][A-z0-9]+$/
```

You need to use:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/
```

As range `[A-z]` consists of non alpha characters also like `[`, `]`, `^` etc. (basically anything from 91-96 ASCII code).

Also better to change quantifier `+` by `*` since your input can contain just a single character.

Answer (score 6):

Your Regex requires two characters (not the same as letters btw) because you are looking for one character that is a letter, and at least one (`+`) letter or digit.

To better get string starting with a letter, then any other character you need:

```
^[A-Za-z].*$
```

the `^` means start of line

the `[A-Za-z]` gets only letters, upper or lower

the `.*` gets literally any character, 0 or more times

the `$` denotes the end of the string

Answer (score 4):

Replace `+` modifier with `*` (changing the meaning from "1 or more" to "0 or more").

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/
---------------------^
```

Make sure to change the `+` to `*` so that it matches 0 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this

```
 # ^(?i)[a-z][a-z0-9]*$

 ^           # BOS
 (?i)        # Ignore case
 [a-z]       # a-z case insensitive
 [a-z0-9]*   # Same as [^\W_]
 $           # EOS
```